# Could not load file or assembly Telerik.Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4, sitefinity-5

having some issues upgrading my Sitefinity 4.1.1339.0 installation to 4.3 (and ultimately to Sitefinity 5).  It is giving me the following error:

> > Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Sitefinity, Version=4.1.1339.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I was thinking it was the /bin/Telerik.Sitefinity.dll file but everything seems to be updated in there.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: are you using the Sitefinity project manager to upgrade the project? Something you might check is for any hard-coded references to that version such as @Register tags in user controls, master pages or web.config. Something like the Find in Files option of Notepad++ can help you locate the reference...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Josh, plus you might try looking through all your files in the App_Data\Sitefinity\Configuration folder. I had to update all of the references in those files manually for some reason to match the exact DLL version. Make sure you completely restart your cassini/IIS/sitefinity instance to pick up the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'assemblyBinding' in your Sitefinity web.config, you will need to update that section of the config to the latest dll versions. Assembly Binding is a common solution to map out of date third party Sitefinity modules/plugins to the current Sitefinity dlls.

The following are correct versions for Sitefinity 5.1.3210. Note that Telerik.Web.UI is a different version as it is from a different Telerik product line.

```
<!-- From web.config - not complete file -->
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="5.1.3210.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Sitefinity.Model" publicKeyToken="b28c218413bdf563" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="5.1.3210.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="2012.2.607.40"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

If you will be upgrading through many versions 4.1 -> 4.4 -> 5.0 -> 5.1, you may wish to comment out this section of the config until you are complete with your upgrades, then add it back in. Otherwise, you'll have to edit these three lines after each upgrade.

Note: to get the dll version, browse to the bin folder. Right click dll file, click properties, then select the 'details' tab.